# How to get information from Web Service?

Tags: php, android, web, service

I need to get information from php web service, but when I do HttpPost in android
The application breaks jusrt in  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

this is my Android code

```
public String getHttp(){
    String jsonResult ="";
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://android.0fees.us/escuela.php");
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
          jsonResult = convertStreamtoString(
                response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonResult;
}

private String convertStreamtoString(InputStream resultado) throws IOException{
    if(resultado != null){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String con = "";
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(resultado, "UTF-8"));

            while((con = br.readLine())!= null){
                sb.append(con).append("'n");
            }

        }finally{
            resultado.close();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

and this is my PHP code

```
<?php 
 include ('conex.php');
       $result = mysql_query("Select nombre FROM escuela") or die("No se realizo");
       $json = array();
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
              while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                   $json[]= $row;
               }
        }
        echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

I hope you can  help me, thank you

Comment: What do you mean the application breaks? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: Yes I'm getting an exception that close my application

Comment: Ok, what is the exception? Why don't you post some log output, maybe a stack trace?

Comment: Well, I cann't get it, when I execute the method don't return any information about it, I mean the application just end

Comment: Are you using Logcat?

Comment: No, I'm not using it

Comment: , Well do!  Do it! And why this subject?

Comment: Just I'm doing it.

I'm sorry, I wanted to publish two topics but I confused the questions and I'm learning how to use this forum.
Well, I need to get information from a PHP web service, but I do the request my appliation breaks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping me.

I get to solve it, I make a new class that allows me to do it without problems, I just extend AsyncTask, and put my code in doInBackground:

```
public class HttpRequest extends AsyncTask {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
    String jsonResult ="";
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://android.0fees.us/escuela.php");
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        jsonResult = convertStreamtoString(
                response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MainActivity.a = jsonResult;
    return jsonResult;
}

private String convertStreamtoString(InputStream resultado) throws IOException{
    if(resultado != null){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String con = "";
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(resultado, "UTF-8"));

            while((con = br.readLine())!= null){
                sb.append(con).append("'n");
            }

        }finally{
            resultado.close();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

}